# Acess S3 from a pod in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am new to Kubernetes and I am transitioning some of the apps to K8S Cluster.
I have tremendous use of S3 in the containers that I used through Roles in AWS.
I have configured a 2 node cluster using kubeadm using Ec2 instances(not EKS).
But I am stuck as whenever I run the container through pods I get error:

```
**Could not connect to the endpoint URL:"https://<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/**
```

I have IAM roles attached to the Ec2 instances that are configured as master and nodes.
Please suggest the best way to establish S3 connection through pods.
Any document/gitrepo link will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to connect AWS S3 bucket on your container? Is it aws-cli or Any programming language AWS SDK or AWS CDK or other? Have you check/troubleshoot connectivity like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-could-not-connect-endpoint-url/)

Comment: Connection to S3 is through Python Boto3. But it didn't store credentials and utilized IAM roles associated with EC2 to run this.

Comment: To troubleshoot and find root cause, I would suggest to perform [these](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-could-not-connect-endpoint-url/) checks within your container. Furthermore, Also check [VPC flow logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) to any network traffic rejection.

Comment: make sure you have Internet access from your EC2 instances

Answer (score 0):

- First, define a trust relationship allowing both EC2 instances and Kubernetes pods to assume this role that you already created.
  Example Trust Relationship JSON (trust-policy.json):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

- In your Kubernetes Deployment YAML, annotate the pod with the IAM role ARN:

```
annotations:
  iam.amazonaws.com/role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/AwsIamRoleAccessToS3Bucket
```

- Update your S3 bucket policy to include the IAM role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/AwsIamRoleAccessToS3Bucket",
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:Put*",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::your-s3-bucket-name/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::your-s3-bucket-name"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Ensure "your-s3-bucket-name" is replaced with your actual S3 bucket name.

- Execute inside the Kubernetes container `aws sts get-caller-identity` and verify that the output reflects the correct IAM role.
- Run S3 command to list objects `aws s3api list-objects --bucket your-s3-bucket-name`
- Ensure the output returns a list of S3 objects, confirming successful IAM role assumption.

By following these steps and verification checks, you can ensure that your Kubernetes pods are correctly assuming the IAM role and have the necessary permissions to interact with the specified S3 bucket.